# The resource handler is not disabling cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a Spring boot 2 and angular application (Book Store application - the admin can add new books or edit existing books). I want to serve images which are kept in `resources/static/images` path. When I add a new images through api call, it works perfectly, but when I try to replace the image with different image (when trying to edit the book), the image gets replaced with new image when I check the folder through file-explorer, but when I visit the link `http://localhost:8181/images/16.png` it shows the old image. In eclipse, if I right click the project and click refresh then `http://localhost:8181/images/16.png` shows correct image.

For preventing this issue, I have written the below code so it prevents caching of `static/images`, but it's not working.

--resource handler

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    
      @Override public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      
      // Register resource handler for images
          System.out.println("indisde cache images");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/").setCachePeriod(0);
      }
     
    
}
```

--spring application

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookStoreApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookStoreApplication.class, args);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {   
          
          User user2=new User(); 
          user2.setUserName("admin");
          user2.setPassword(SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode("admin"));
          user2.setEmail("admin@admin.com");
          user2.setEnabled(true);
          user2.setFirstName("adminFirstName"); 
          user2.setLastName("adminLastName");
          user2.setPhone("223456789");
          Role role2=new Role();
          role2.setRoleId((long) 2);
          role2.setRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN"); 
          UserRole userRole2=new UserRole(user2,role2);
          Set<UserRole> userRoles2=new HashSet<UserRole>();
          userRoles2.add(userRole2);
          userService.CreateUser(user2, userRoles2);
         
    }
}
```

--controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity uploadImage(@RequestParam(name = "id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        Iterator<String> imageNames = multipartRequest.getFileNames();
        System.out.println(imageNames);
        MultipartFile imageMutipart = multipartRequest.getFile(imageNames.next());
        byte[] imageBytes = imageMutipart.getBytes();

        String imageNameNew = id + ".png";

        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/images/" + imageNameNew)));
        bout.write(imageBytes);
        bout.flush();
        bout.close();
        return new ResponseEntity("Upload success", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return new ResponseEntity("Upload failed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

--angular service

```
   upload(bookId: number) {
    this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:8181/book/add/image?id="+bookId, [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }

  modifyImage(bookId: number){
    if(this.filesToUpload.length>0){
        this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:8181/book/add/image?id="+bookId, [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using the below resource handler

```
@Configuration
public class AdditionalResourceWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/media/**").addResourceLocations("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/media/");
  }
}
```